# Verify SQL Server statistics

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cardinality

From my ASP.NET app using EF Core I get a query to the database that has quite a few joins (13). When I execute it, it works - but it takes 25 seconds to complete.

However, when I use "Legacy Cardinality Estimation" in database options the execution is just instant. As I understand the cardinality estimation is done based on statistics, therefore I executed `exec sp_updatestats`. While once it helped on the same db (but different query), this time it did not.

Therefore the first question that comes to my mind is: how do I verify the statistics are correct? And if they are why would cardinality estimator make bad choices?

Or more generally: how do I approach this problem without resorting to above mentioned option (turning on something legacy doesn't sound right)?

Answer (score 0):

a good start to check is the indexes rowcnt/rows. you can usually see the issue here, though fixing it is either by updating statistics or getting the latest CU (cumulative update) or SP (service pack), and even then it may not be patched yet.

I had this problem in 2014 sp2 and sp3, the service packs alone did not fix the cardinality estimator. You need to get the latest Cumulative Update.

```
declare 
     @table_name varchar(128) = 'TableName'
    ,@schema_name varchar(128) = 'dbo'

/* 2014 and after I believe */
select max(p.rows) rows from sys.tables t 
inner join sys.indexes i on t.object_id = i.object_id
inner join sys.partitions p on t.object_id = p.object_id and p.index_id = i.index_id -- current-ish
where t.name = @table_name and schema_name(t.schema_id) = @schema_name

/* 2008 to 2012 I believe */
select max(i.rows)
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.sysindexes i on i.id = t.object_id -- the old dbo.sysindexes becomes a view
where t.name = @table_name and schema_name(t.schema_id) = @schema_name

/* 2000 and possibly earlier */
select max(i.rows)
from sys.tables t
inner join dbo.sysindexes i on i.id = t.object_id -- a real live table, still selectable
where t.name = @table_name and schema_name(t.schema_id) = @schema_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when it comes to CE everything is common ground. You said it yourself. 25 seconds vs < 1 seconds, and both used the same stats, updated or not, same indexes, same query and so on. 
I had worked quite a lot about CE choice and it comes that (after stats, indexes and all standard recommended actions) one estimator may work very good and the other very bad. And this can be at the very same query with 1 filter difference or 2 different queries producing exact equal results.
In most cases both perform well or acceptable. Sometimes however 1 of them total screw up. There you must either use the legacy CE 2012 or make your statement 'CE 2014 friendly'.

Or, if your statements have a clear identity on your code and this is for example 'mystatementA021' then you can keep your own stats and select CE 2012 or 2014. But that is a longer story.